# C++ main() vs local function initialization of object

Tags: c++, function, class, object, program-entry-point

I was reading inside the c++ object module,there is a topic about default constructor.if we initialize a object of some class in function like

**CODE**

```
class Test
{
   public:
   void show(){cout<<x<<endl;}
   int x;
};
void func()
{
  Test t;
  t.show();
}
```

**OUTPUT**

Output is 0

but in book it is given that global objects are zero initialized and default 
constructor for the creation of this object doesn't run. I'm bit confused about it.
is object zero initialized in local function and to some arbitrary value in main???

Comment: hint: if you don't initialize something, it can have any value (except for globals and statics). 0 is one possible value that an uninitialized `int` could have.

Comment: The value of uninitialized local (non-static) variables is *indeterminate*, and using uninitialized data leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: The variable 'x' isn't initialised at all in the class. You don't even have a default constructor. What's more is that there's no point in the function show() when you can access the said variable directly. What's more is you're even outputting an uninitialised variable. Go figure!

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't provide a default constructor, a local object may not be zero initialized and may contain garbage.

This is defined in the standard:

> Section **8.5/11**: If no initializer is specified for an object, the
>   object is default-initialized; if no initialization is performed, an
>   object with automatic or dynamic storage duration has indeterminate
>   value.

For static and globals:

> Section **3.6.2/2**:  Variables with static storage duration (...) 
>   shall be zero-initialized **before any other initialization takes
>   place**.

If you have a default constructor, it is called in every case (unless you specify an initializer).  This is true for global objects as for locals.

***Suggestion:***  You could experiment this with the following default constructor:

```
Test() {
    cout << "Default ctor: old x:" << x << endl;   // for curisosity
    x = 0;  // now x is 0 for sure 
}
```

You'll notice that for global objects,  old x is always 0, whereas for local objects, old x may be garbage.

Comment: even if i provide default constructor the value remains zero.but if initialize object in main then value in x is arbitrary.

Comment: Note that Christophe said "may contain garbage". There is an important difference between an object containing zero under certain circumstances and having the guarantee that it contains zero. Without initialization, there is no guarantee, so don't rely on the object containing zero.

Comment: ok i got it,last one question.is default constructor is synthesized for class when i create the object of class.according to book it doesn't.

Comment: In most cases there is an implicit default constructor when you don't provide one (otherwhise you could not define ay object for the class !). But this constructor doesn't do much, and it doesn't initialize any member variable.  In some cases there is no implicit default constructor  e.g. not trivial unions and other kind of special constructs.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize x as x = 0 (or any other number you want it to be) by using a defualt constructor in your class definition. From there you can manipulate the data accordingly, or just enter the value you want x to hold in the defualt constructor.

```
class Test
{
   public:
   void show(){cout<<x<<endl;}
   int x;

//Defualt Constructor
   test(){

    x=0;
    }
};
```